# how to use both the log writer and app insights within azure function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'd like to send trace and other events to both the `ILogger` as well as application insights.

I know that I can simply do this:

```
    [FunctionName ("OnSomethingHttpTriggered")]
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync ([QueueTrigger ("myq", Connection = "StorageAccountConnection")] string payload, ILogger log) {
        var telemetry = new TelemetryClient {
        InstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY")
        };
        log.LogInformation ($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {payload}");
        telemetry.TrackEvent ($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {payload}");

        var isPayloadValidSchema = SchemaValidator.IsValid (payload);
        if (!isPayloadValidSchema) {
            log.LogError ($"This visit is not valid {payload}");
            telemetry.TrackEvent ($"This visit is not valid {payload}");
            return;
        }
    }
```

But as you can see I would need to double my code each time for `ILogger` and `TelemetryClient`.

**How do I avoid this repetition?**

Comment: Could you perhaps DI in your own `SuperLogger` object (similar to what you did with `ILogger` I suspect), that has `ILogger` and `TelemetryClient` as constructor injected dependencies? Then call a method in your own `SuperLogger` that then calls both methods.

Comment: ILogger output  is sent to Application Insights by default once we have appinsights turned on, is this what you want?

Comment: @JerryLiu yes exactly. you're saying i dont need to even use the `telemtryclient` ?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' Truly we don't need it unless you have some custom event to track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need `telemtryclient` to send output of `ILogger`, those will [appear as traces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#write-logs-in-c-functions) in Application Insights by default once we set `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` in application settings(locally in Values of local.setting.json). We use `telemtryclient` to send [custom telemetry data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions).